# Validator in DataGrid, using parameters from row

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I have a situation, where in database, i have list of items, which contains such information:

```
[Item]
* ItemName
* ItemPackagingSize
* AvailableQuantity
```

User can input how many items he wants to get(quantity), but that quantity must follow this condition:

```
if(quantity % ItemPackagingSize == 0)
    isValid = true;
else
    isValid = false;
```

**What ASP.NET validator i should use, to check this thing? Or maybe there is other way, to do this?**

For example, for AvailableQuantity i use this:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator" ControlToValidate="OrderQuantity" runat="server" Type="Double" MaximumValue='<%# Container.DataItem["LeftQuantity"] %>' ErrorMessage="Quantity entered is higher than available quantity"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Range Validator will only check for input that falls between two parameters - a low and a high.

It seems your requirement is to ensure that customers only purchase full packages - you can buy a six-pack, but no individual bottles.

You can create a Custom Validator that access the code you've written - this would work fine, but involves server-side validation. Here's an example: http://asp.net-tutorials.com/validation/custom-validator/

Another option would be a RegularExpression (RegEx) Validator - uses client-side validation. RegEx can utilize the modulus (%) operator to test your condition. However, you will have to dynamically create a separate RegEx validator for each 'ItemPackagingSize' that varies with different products.

Finally, another option might be to redefine what you mean by quantity to the user: where a quantity of 1 means 1 six-pack.

Comment: I already though of all these solutions, but it seems like, best one is to use CustomValidator, which uses ClientValidationFunction, which finds hidden field, in row and then does the check.

If someone is interested here is ClientValidationFunction:
`function validatePackage(oSrc, args) {
   var value = $('input[name$="hf_PackageItemsCount"]', $(oSrc).parent())[0].value;
   args.IsValid = (Number(args.Value.replace(",", ".")) % Number(value.replace(",", ".")) == 0);
}`